# 'str' object has no attribute 'name' Django rest api video post error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my django rest api app for uploading videos,my models.py file is below,

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from likevideos.models import Likevideo

class Video(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    video_file = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Video by {self.id}: {self.title}"

    @property
    def like_count(self):
        return self.likevideos.count()

    @property
    def comment_count(self):
        return self.videocomments.count()
```

Here is my views.py file,

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, filters
from friends_chats.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Video
from .serializers import VideoSerializer

class VideoListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer

    filter_backends = [
        filters.OrderingFilter,
        filters.SearchFilter,
    ]
    search_fields = [
        'owner__username',
        'title',
    ]
    ordering_fields = [
        'like_count',
        'comment_count',
        'likevideos__created_at',
    ]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

class VideoDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer
```

Here is my serializer,

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError as DjangoValidationError
from .models import Video
from .models import Likevideo

class VideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    likevideo_id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    like_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    comment_count = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ['id', 'owner', 'title', 'video_file', 'description', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'is_owner','likevideo_id','like_count','comment_count']


    def validate_video_file(self, value):
        # Check file extension
        valid_extensions = ['mp4', 'avi', 'mkv', 'mp3']  
        extension_validator = FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=valid_extensions)
        
        try:
            extension_validator(value.name)
        except DjangoValidationError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(str(e))

        # Check file size
        max_size = 50 * 1024 * 1024  
        if value.size > max_size:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(f"File size too large. Max size is {max_size} bytes.")

        return value

    


    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.user == obj.owner


    def get_likevideo_id(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        try:
            likevideo_instance = Likevideo.objects.get(owner=user, video=obj)
            return likevideo_instance.id
        except Likevideo.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_likevideo_count(self, obj):
        return obj.like_count
    
    def get_comment_count(self, obj):
        return obj.comment_count
```

I am getting error for uploading video,

> AttributeError at /videos/ 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

I tried with changing the line validate video file from extension_validator(value.name) to value.title or value.file.title

Comment: When you receive a file through a Django REST Framework serializer, the file is wrapped in a `UploadedFile` object. The `.name` attribute should be accessed on this `UploadedFile` object, not on a string. The error suggests that the value in `validate_video_file` is a string, which is generally unexpected.

Make sure that the value is indeed a `UploadedFile` object. You can add a print statement or use a debugger to inspect the value type before moving to next step.